Ramanujan type identity for level 3 and Weber function
Let
\begin{align}
& F_1(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac12 \right)_n \left( \frac16 \right)_n \left( \frac56 \right)_n}{(1)_n^3} \left( \frac{1728 x}{(x-16)^3} \right)^n, \\
& F_2(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac12 \right)_n \left( \frac14 \right)_n \left( \frac34 \right)_n}{(1)_n^3} \left( \frac{-256 x}{(x-64)^2} \right)^n, \\
& F_4(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac12 \right)_n^3}{(1)_n^3} \left( \frac{x}{64} \right)^n.
\end{align}
Then, the identities
$$
F_1(x)=2 \sqrt{\frac{16-x}{64-x}} \, F_2(x)= 
\frac14 \sqrt{16-x} \, F_4(x),
$$
hold and $x=f^{24}(\tau)$, where $f(\tau)$ is the Weber function.
QUESTION:
Find (if they exist) explicit functions $B(x)$ and $A(x)$ rational and algebraic respectively such that $F_1(x)=A(x) F_3(x)$, where
$$
F_3(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \frac12 \right)_n \left( \frac13 \right)_n \left( \frac23 \right)_n}{(1)_n^3} B(x)^n.
$$

@Jesus_Guillera. By Clausen's identity this equivalent question is simpler involving Gauss hypergeometric function. Find algebraic functions $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ such that $$,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{4};1;x\right)=\alpha(x),_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{6};1;\beta(x)\right)$$ If this transformation exists you are done. See Lemma 2.1 Mitsuo Kato, Algebraic Transformations of $_3F_2$.  https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/fesi/51/2/51_2_221/_pdf/-char/en

Dear Jesus, why did you remove my edit ? it is $x=f^{24}$ and not $f=x^{24}$.

Sorry Henri, you are right. Now I have fixed ithat as you edited it

The non-existence of rational $B(x) $ is probably one of the reasons Ramanujan did not offer many series for $1/\pi$ based on $F_3(x)$.

The answer is no, this transformation does not exist. This is a Corollary of Theorem 2.2 in Mitsuo Kato article.
Kato's theorem proves the existence of algebraic transformations between $\,_3F_2$ functions that are projectively equivalent. It is comprehensive and exhaustive by proving all 15 cases where this equivalence exists.
If $F_\ell(\zeta)=\,_3F_2(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{s},1-\frac{1}{s};1,1;\zeta)$ with $\ell=1,2,3,4$ for $s=6,4,3,2$ respectively, is a non-logarithmic solution of the 3rd order Fuchsian differential equation and $\vartheta=\zeta\frac{d}{d\zeta}$ then $$\left[\vartheta^3-\zeta(\vartheta +\frac{1}{2})(\vartheta +\frac{1}{s})(\vartheta +1-\frac{1}{s})\right]F_\ell(\zeta)=0$$ It has 3 singular points $\infty$, 0 and 1 with local exponents {$\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{s},1-\frac{1}{s}$} at $\zeta=\infty$, {$0,0,0$} at $\zeta=0$, {$0,1,\frac{1}{2}$} at $\zeta=1$ and {$0,1,2$} elsewhere.
Since there is just one singular point, $\zeta=1$, where local exponents differ by a positive integer $=1$ and the irreducibility condition holds (all numerator and each difference between numerator and denominator parameters $\notin\mathbb{Z}$), the differential equation has an irreducible monodromy group and theorem conditions are fulfilled.
The projectively equivalent identity between $F_4$ and $F_2$ is proven either applying Theorem's point (2.1) ($_3F_2$ Quadratic Transformation) or from an induced $_2F_1$ Clausen's type transformation in point (2.8).
The projectively equivalent identity between $F_4$ and $F_1$ is proven either applying Theorem's point (2.2) ($_3F_2$ Cubic Transformation) or from an induced $_2F_1$ Clausen's type transformation in point (2.9).
Since we can use transitivity for projectively equivalent identities, it is enough to disprove the existence of the identity between $F_4$ and $F_3$. This follows straigthwise because we must force all local exponents to be 0 at $\zeta=0$ (all denominator's parameters are 1). The non-existence proof is obtained easily since no match exists for any of the 15 cases: 5 $_3F_2$ transformations (points 2.1 - 2.5) and 10 induced Clausen's $_2F_1$ transformations (2.8 - 2.16) with $\lambda_0=0$.
A consequence of this fact is that Ramanujan type identities for level 3 cannot be proven using Weber polynomials. For this level we should switch to other approach of modular forms (R. Russell's). This is clearly seen in this Guillera's Maple worksheet where level 3 for Weber function is excluded.
Kato, Mitsuo, Algebraic transformations of 3F2, Funkc. Ekvacioj, Ser. Int. 51, No. 2, 221-243 (2008). ZBL1168.33307.
